# wow.js don't works correctly with position:relative

Tags: html, css, animate.css, wow.js

I'm building a website and I need some animations. My problem is that I have a block with the following CSS:

```
.description {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

And the block is as follows:

```
<section id="first-section">
  <div class="description wow fadeInUp">
    <!-- Some other content here -->
  </div>
</section>

<section id="second-section">...</section>
```

But when I scroll down the `.description` block performs the animation in `#second-section` and then moves (with no animation) to the right place inside `#first-section` do I make myself clear?

`.description` needs to be positioned that way because of the design but I need to smooth the animation. Any idea why wow is having this issue with my block?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: do you get an error in the console? btw, you might need to provide more details as to why you are animating `.description` yourself (instead of letting the library do it for you)

Comment: @ochi, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: ytcfg is not defined` but it's a youtube error (I have a `<iframe>` with an embed youtube video)

Comment: for the sake of troubleshooting, remove it (for now) and see if something else shows up

Comment: Error occurs in youtube-frame, so it can't case wrong animation behavior

Comment: I did it and works fine, but I need to position it in the bottom of the section, any idea?

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza, can you provide jsfiddle example?